# Ansible playbook hostvars undefined variables

Tags: ansible

Folks,
  The following code is producing errors.

code:

```
{% for v in hostvars.iteritems() %}
    {{ v['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'][0] }}  {{ v['ansible_hostname'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

error:

```
{'msg': "One or more undefined variables: 'tuple object' has no attribute 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'", 'failed': True}
```

What should this look like if i wanted an /etc/hosts file like:

```
192.168.111.222 hostnameA
192.168.111.211 hostnameB
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Error message

> 'tuple object' has no attribute 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'

, it is clear that your hosts' facts does not either contain ansible_all_ipv4_addresses inside where you were searching or syntax parser caught you off-guard :)

Let's try this:

```
{% for minion in groups['web'] %}
 {{ hostvars[minion]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'][0] }} {{ hostvars[minion]['ansible_hostname'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Consider we lay out our inventory like this

```
[web]
192.168.111.222 hostnameA
192.168.111.211 hostnameB
```

Hope it solves your problem. Cheers !!

Comment: The issue is hostvars.iteritems()...  switching to groups solved my problems.

Comment: Did something change? In 1.9.4 this fails: fatal: [data1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'"}